# looping through rows of dataframe in R to create vector based on conditions doesn´t work

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTnhD.jpg)I am trying to create a binary vector by looping through my dataframe row by row. If the first non-zero number in the row is a 1, I want a 1 to be printed into the vector, if it is a -1 I want a 0 printed. The dataframe includes 1, 0 and -1 as entries. My code so far looks like this but doesn´t output the desired vector (only the first entry is correct, every other entry is just a zero).

```
counter <- 0 
Choice <- vector(length = nrow(Temp))
for (row in seq_along(nrow(Temp))) {
  
  counter <- counter + 1
  
  Stereo <- Temp[row, 1]
  Mono  <- Temp[row, 2]
  MS <- Temp[row, 3]
  HT1RB1 <- Temp[row, 4]
  HT0RB0 <- Temp[row, 5]
  ITD0.8SS100 <- Temp[row, 6]
  ITD1.2SS60 <- Temp[row, 7]
  ITD1.6SS100 <- Temp[row, 8]

  
  if(!(Stereo == 0 | Stereo == -1)) {
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1 
  } else if (!(Stereo == 1 | Stereo == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  } else if (!(Mono == -1 | Mono == 0)) {
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  } else if (!(Mono == 1 | Mono == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0 
  }else if (!(MS == -1 | MS == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  } else if (!(MS == 1 | MS == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  } else if (!(HT1RB1 == -1 | HT1RB1 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  }  else if (!(HT1RB1 == 1 | HT1RB1 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  } else if (!(HT0RB0 == -1 | HT0RB0 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  } else if (!(HT0RB0 == 1 | HT0RB0 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  } else if (!(ITD0.8SS100 == -1 | ITD0.8SS100 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  } else if (!(ITD0.8SS100 == 1 | ITD0.8SS100 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  } else if (!(ITD1.2SS60 == -1 | ITD1.2SS60 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  } else if (!(ITD1.2SS60 == 1 | ITD1.2SS60 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  } else if (!(ITD1.6SS100 == -1 | ITD1.6SS100 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 1
  } else if (!(ITD1.6SS100 == 1 | ITD1.6SS100 == 0)){
    Choice[[counter]] <- 0
  }
}
```

I would be so grateful if someone was able to help, I have looked at this for way to long now and totally lost perspective.
Sorry that the image quality is so shitty :/
Thank you! :)

Comment: please include some sample data (please use `dput( mydata )` ) to reproduce your problem with.

Comment: Try to avoid using `for` loops for this type in task in R. This can easily be vectorized and will be a lot simpler and more readable. I'd suggest using `dplyr::case_when` for your multiple conditions.

Comment: @Wimpel I am not sure I am allowed, as it is company data ... I can share a screenshot tho I think

Comment: @csgroen I will try that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should simplify your life a lot.

Instead of a for loop, use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package,
and, instead of that long chain of else if, use `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)
Temp %>%
 mutate(Choice = case_when(
  
  !(Stereo      ==  0 | Stereo      == -1) ~ 1, 
  !(Stereo      ==  1 | Stereo      ==  0) ~ 0,
  !(Mono        == -1 | Mono        ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(Mono        ==  1 | Mono        ==  0) ~ 0, 
  !(MS          == -1 | MS          ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(MS          ==  1 | MS          ==  0) ~ 0,
  !(HT1RB1      == -1 | HT1RB1      ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(HT1RB1      ==  1 | HT1RB1      ==  0) ~ 0,
  !(HT0RB0      == -1 | HT0RB0      ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(HT0RB0      ==  1 | HT0RB0      ==  0) ~ 0,
  !(ITD0.8SS100 == -1 | ITD0.8SS100 ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(ITD0.8SS100 ==  1 | ITD0.8SS100 ==  0) ~ 0,
  !(ITD1.2SS60  == -1 | ITD1.2SS60  ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(ITD1.2SS60  ==  1 | ITD1.2SS60  ==  0) ~ 0,
  !(ITD1.6SS100 == -1 | ITD1.6SS100 ==  0) ~ 1,
  !(ITD1.6SS100 ==  1 | ITD1.6SS100 ==  0) ~ 0))
```

---

For a good reproducible example, there is no need to share private data or to post a screenshot, just create fake data that look believable.

For example, you can use this:

```
Temp <- replicate(8, sample(-1:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
colnames(Temp) <- c("Stereo",
                    "Mono",
                    "MS",
                    "HT1RB1",
                    "HT0RB0",
                    "ITD0.8SS100",
                    "ITD1.2SS60",
                    "ITD1.6SS100")
Temp <- as.data.frame(Temp)
```

Comment: That looks better now for sure, but it doesn´t give me the right vector output for some rows where -1 appears before 1. But it gave me a different approach, maybe i´ll figure it out now :) Thank you so much !!

Comment: I've added an edit to help you out with a good reproducible example. Also, I've realised you don't need `rowwise` because `case_when` is already vectorised.

Answer (score 1):

Reading what you want for your desired output, I think the approach could be changed.

Here, I loop through the elements of the row and break when I find the first non-zero element, which is added to `vec`.

```
Temp <- replicate(8, sample(-1:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
colnames(Temp) <- c("Stereo",
                    "Mono",
                    "MS",
                    "HT1RB1",
                    "HT0RB0",
                    "ITD0.8SS100",
                    "ITD1.2SS60",
                    "ITD1.6SS100")
Temp <- as.data.frame(Temp)
Temp
#>    Stereo Mono MS HT1RB1 HT0RB0 ITD0.8SS100 ITD1.2SS60 ITD1.6SS100
#> 1       1   -1  0      1      1           0         -1          -1
#> 2       0   -1  1     -1      0           1          1          -1
#> 3      -1    0 -1      1      0           0          1           0
#> 4      -1    0  1      0      0          -1         -1          -1
#> 5       0    1  1     -1      1           0         -1           1
#> 6       0   -1  0     -1      0           0          0           1
#> 7      -1    0  0      0     -1           1          1          -1
#> 8       1   -1  1     -1      1          -1         -1          -1
#> 9       0   -1  1      0     -1           1         -1          -1
#> 10      0    1 -1      0     -1          -1          1          -1

vec <- rep(0, nrow(Temp))
for (i in 1:nrow(Temp)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(Temp)) {
        if (Temp[i,j] > 0) {
            vec[i] <- 1
            break
        } 
        else if (Temp[i,j] < 0) {
            vec[i] <- -1 
            break
        }
    }
}
vec
#>  [1]  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1
```

I hope I interpreted the desired outcome correctly. Good luck!